# Send deleted rows to another table

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say that I have a table X and table Y.
I wanted to delete rows from table X and I wanted to send the deleted rows to table Y. How would I do that? Can someone please help me. :( thanks a lot.

Comment: Show your code. Tell us what you have done so far and then you'll get help. People are going to downvote your question this way.

Comment: why do you want to do this, how about having a column attribute is_deleted or deleted_at ? If so look at soft delete

Comment: this is the function i created:
 function deleteData($fname, $connect){
  $connect = connect();
  $sql = "DELETE FROM oldtable WHERE firstname = '$fname';";
  $sql .= "INSERT INTO newtable select * from oldtable where firstname = '$fname';";
  $sql_connect = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 }

Comment: function deleteData($fname, $connect){
 $connect = connect();
 $sql = "DELETE FROM oldtable WHERE firstname = '$fname';";
 $sql .= "INSERT INTO newtable select * from oldtable where firstname = '$fname';";
 $sql_connect = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 }
 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  $fname=$_POST['firstname'];
  deleteData($fname, connect());
 }

?>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Table X & Y are the exact structure

First:

```
insert into tableY select * from tableX where condition;
```

Then:

```
delete from tableX where condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be help you

```
mysql> create table X(id int)
-> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.51 sec)


mysql> create table Y(id int)
-> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.34 sec)

mysql> delimiter |
mysql> create trigger on_delete before delete on X for each row begin 
       insert into Y set id =  OLD.id;
       end ;
       Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
mysql> insert into x (1),(2);

mysql> delete from X;

mysql> select * from Y;

      +------+
      | id   |
      +------+
      |    1 |
      |    2 |
      +------+
   2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

you can do this with mysql trigger.more reference [learn about trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)